TypeError: functions.firestore.document is not a function
I have this Google function:
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();

     exports.sendMessageNotification = functions.firestore
       .document('<path>') 
    .onCreate(
        async (snapshot, context) => {
            console.log("onCreate pozvan");
            const buildingId = context.params.buildingId;
            const data = snapshot.data();

            const title = String(data.title);
            const text = String(data.text);

            console.log("buildingId = " + buildingId);
            console.log("title = " + title);
            console.log("text = " + text);

            const message = {
                notification: {
                    title: title,
                    body: text,
                },
                topic: buildingId,
            };

            console.log("notification = " + message);

            try {
                const response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
                console.log('❤️:', response);
                return {
                    success: true,
                    response: response
                };
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('☠️ Error', error);
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Error: ', error);
            }
        }
    );

When I did firebase deploy before, everything worked perfectly, but now I get the following error:
TypeError: functions.firestore.document is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/flutter_projects/ax/functions/index.js:6:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at loadModule (/Users/me/flutter_projects/ax/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/runtime/loader.js:40:16)
    at loadStack (/Users/me/flutter_projects/ax/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/runtime/loader.js:157:23)
    at /Users/me/flutter_projects/ax/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/bin/firebase-functions.js:56:56

How can I solve this problem?

Can you tell us what happened since the last time you deployed? Did you upgrade anything?  Perhaps you are now actually using the new v2 API instead of the old v1 in your code? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd

You are right. That was the problem. Thanks!
